# hide or close the dijit.editor after editing is done

Tags: javascript, dojo

can u please tell me how to hide or close the dijit editor once the editing is done.. i have used an auto expanding dijit.editor.. so when i click on the div,the editor opens up.. so after editing my content i cant close / hide the editor to again get back the div with updated/edited content.. can u please help me by posting the code for this hiding or closing of editor??

```
enter code here
<script>
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
var editor = dijit.byId("myEditor");
editor .onLoadDeferred.addCallback(function(){
editor.attr("value", "<b>This is new content.</b>");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really "close" the editor to get back to a plain div. I suggest that when the user is "done editing" (using onBlur or whatever), you extract the value as HTML, destroy the editor, and re-insert the extracted HTML. Something like this:

```
var parentNode = editor.domNode.parentNode;
var updatedContent = editor.get("value");
editor.destroyRecursive();
dojo.place(updatedContent, parentNode);
```